# Creating a UDF to convert comma separated string to rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column data like this:

```
    A
100,100,120
80,100,120
20,60,120
```

I want to create a User Defined Function (using vba) to generate below result

```
   A
  100
  100
  120
  80
  100
  120
  20
  60
  120
```

I know that this can be done by using "Text to column" feature and Paste "Transpose", however, due to the fact that data size of column A is still growing so I prefer using UDF for updating the whole file as once.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To"). Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: I start  with Split() but got stuck when trying to input the result array into a column

Comment: A UDF sets the value of the cell in which it is placed.  It cannot write to other cells.

Comment: Thanks for that info @TonyDallimore. I have solve my question by go for a different approach. By adding additional arguments for the UDF, the code is now much more simple and my function works perfectly.